# Somthing wrong with this Unit Test EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-code-first

m new in Unit test and EF Code first
Im trying to test function to add data into database by using EF. 
I dont know whats wrong with my code, it should fail but it Passes
Here is m Test function

```
[TestClass]
public class ProspectControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {     
     DataContext context = new DataContext();
           Seller c = new Seller
           {
               SellerName = "test20",
               SellerDivision = "test20",
               SellerCity  = "City410",
               Active = true,

           };
        context.sellers.Add(c);

           context.SaveChanges();


           Seller s = (from d in context.sellers
                       where d.SellerId == c.SellerId
                       select d).Single();
           //This shouldent pass because there is no records in the db !
           c.SellerName.Equals(s.SellerName);

       }
    }
}
```

Here is m class

```
  public class Seller
{
    [Key]
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }
    public string SellerDiv { get; set; }
    public string SellerCity { get; set; }

    public Boolean Active { get; set; }

    public Div Div { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Prospect> prospects { get; set; }
}
```

Another quastion, Does this test store any data into db ?should i be able to se the records in the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following lines

```
//This should fail
c.SellerName.Equals("asdfsadfasdfsadfsadf");
```

With

```
Assert.AreEqual<string>("asdfsadfasdfsadfsadf", c.SellerName);
```

Assert statements verifies your test output.

In case you are verifying whether correct object got inserted in DB or not then verify using following assert statements.

```
Assert.IsNotNULL(s);
Assert.AreEqual<string>("asdfsadfasdfsadfsadf",c.SellerName);
```

Comment: Watch m edit 

               Assert.AreEqual(c.SellerName, s.SellerName); passes althowgh there is no data in the db

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Mock in your test method to perform action like inserting into database( **but it won't insert the query in database that will used to run the code but it will not save it database because of using Mock**).

**Note : Use MOCK concept to achieve this.**

```
Assert.AreEqual(c.SellerName, "asdfsadfasdfsadfsadf");
```

And use asserts to check the values.

Comment: Please let me know if you didn't aware of MOCK concept. It is an important one in Unit test.